# Virtualenv cannot specify minor Python version

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

virtualenv will not let me specify 2.7.5 in the command (the version of python I need), it only allows 2.7. However, specifying 2.7 gives me 2.7.4, the version below the one I need. Is this an inherent limitation of virtualenv or am I missing something?

```
$ virtualenv test/test --no-site-packages --python=python2.7
```

System is Ubuntu 13.04, which has Python 2.6.8, 2.7.4 and 3.3.1 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download/make/install/apt-get/synaptic python 2.7.5 and point at it's path like so when creating a virtulenv:

```
virtualenv test/test -p /usr/bin/my_2.7.5_directory/python2.7
```

Comment: That's a logical, obvious solution. Apparently it's been a long day. *sigh*.

Thank you. I'm approving this in advance even though I won't be able to try it til tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, let me know if there are any other problems, and happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, `--python` just lets you specify which *already-installed* Python you want to use. In order to use a particular version, you need to install it first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this generalizes to anything in your path (e.g., in `/usr/local/bin`)

Comment: Off the top of my head I couldn't remember if there would be naming conflict (as in, both python 2.7.4 and python 2.7.5 both occupy python2.7), which is why i recommended the path option to be more explicit. It probably isn't an issue though.

Comment: The reason I can't find a .deb it seems is because it's not even being targeted for 13.04, but for 13.10 (currently in dev).

Comment: 1) Download http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tgz  2) open terminal, go to download directory (type something like `cd ~/Downloads`), type `tar -xvf Python-2.7.5.tgz` 3) type `cd Python-2.7.5/` 4) type `./configure make` 5) type `make install`